# memoizing a recursion solution (DP)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have written this recursion for the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-with-transaction-fee
I want to know how can we memoize this solution (using a dp array).
or do we have to write recursion in a specific way to memoize it?

```
class Solution {
public:


    int solve(vector<int>& prices,int fee,int i,int profit,int buy,int sell)
    {
        if(i==prices.size())
        {
            if(buy==sell)
                return profit;
            else
                return 0;
        }

        int ans = 0;

        ans = max(ans,solve(prices,fee,i+1,profit,buy,sell));

        if(buy>sell)
        {
            ans = max(ans,solve(prices,fee,i+1,profit+prices[i]-fee,buy,sell+1));
        }
        else 
        {
            ans = max(ans,solve(prices,fee,i+1,profit-prices[i],buy+1,sell));
        }

        return ans;

    }

    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices, int fee) {
        vector<int> diff;
        int sum = 0;
        sum = solve(prices,fee,0,0,0,0);

        return sum;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an array where element i is equal to solve(i). Then, inside your function, you can pass this array through by reference to each call. You add an if/else structure in your function testing if the input you got was defined in the array, if so return arr[input] and if not, run through your normal function except just before you return, you initialize arr[input] to the value you will return.

Comment: I understand that, I tried it but it gives wrong answer on creating a 1d array. I think this is because of other two variables 'buy' and 'sell' which i am changing in each call. is there any way i can create dp array including those variables.?

Comment: Just add two extra dimensions